# Absolute continuity of the ratio of two absolutely continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Will the ratio of two absolutely continuous functions, say $f$ and $g$ where $g$ is non-vanishing, remain absolutely continuous?

Comment: I suspect not without a restriction as to compact domain.  Consider $f(x)=1$ on the real line and $g(x) = e^{-x^2}(cos(x) + 1 + e^{-x^2})$.

Comment: Indeed even the product of two absolutely continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ may fail to be absolutely continuous (e.g. $f(x)=g(x)=x$).  So, should we assume a bounded interval as the given domain?

Comment: @hardmath...Yes a bounded domain suits my purpose...thanks...

Comment: or can the domain just be bounded, open, connected set.

Answer (score 2):

On a closed bounded interval, yes. Indeed, the vector-valued function $\phi(x)=(f(x),g(x))$ is absolutely continuous by assumption, and it takes values in some closed rectangle $R=[a,b]\times [c,d]\subset \mathbb R^2$ with $c>0$. The function $\psi(u,v)=  u/v$ is Lipschitz in this rectangle, since its gradient is bounded. It is easy to see from the definition that post-composition with a Lipschitz function preserves absolute continuity. Hence,  the composition $\psi\circ \phi$ is absolutely continuous, and this is precisely $f/g$.

On an unbounded interval this is not true, examples were pointed out by hardmath in comments. It is still true that $f/g$ is locally absolutely continuous; and generally speaking, on unbounded domains the local form of absolute continuity is more useful.

Comment: @Behaviour...Can the domain just be bounded, open, connected set?.

Comment: That's not enough. Consider $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Ok...Thank you...@Behaviour